# Histogram showing mean of each bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a density graph showing the amount of traffic and animal visits at different times of the day. What I would like to see is the means of amount of cars at the different points along the line. With limited skills in r I have read the other threads here on the site and others but I have a hard time figuring out exactly how I should do. As I have understood it this far I would need to calculate the mean of each bin in the graph and I have played around with this code but with little success:

```
ggplot(speed, aes(x=time_rad, y=LENGTH))+
+   geom_point()+ 
+   stat_summary_bin(fun = "mean",
+                    geom="bar",
+                    binwidth=1
+                    )
```

This is the code for my graph where I would like to include the calculations of the means:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=TimeRad_enter1))+
  geom_density(aes(color=Focal_species))+
  geom_density(data=speed, aes(x=time_rad))+
  labs(y="Density", x="Time of day", title="Density of visits over the day")+
  scale_x_continuous(labels =c("00:00", "07:38", "15:16", "22:56"))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=16, color="black"),
        text = element_text(family="serif"),
        title = element_text(size=20),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14))
```

This is the structure of my speed data:

```
'data.frame':   783463 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ DETECTORREF  : Factor w/ 2 levels "se-lm-lv108n-viltbokeberg2",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ DETECTORNUM  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SOURCE_DATE  : Date, format: "2020-07-08" "2020-07-08" ...
 $ SOURCE_TIME  : chr  "12:11:07" "12:11:12" "12:11:15" "12:11:16" ...
 $ RECEIVED_DATE: Date, format: "2020-07-08" "2020-07-08" ...
 $ RECEIVED_TIME:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ .Data : num  7 12 15 16 18 20 29 51 54 2 ...
  .. ..@ year  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ month : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ day   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ hour  : num  12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
  .. ..@ minute: num  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 ...
 $ SPEED        : num  87 74 75 74 75 75 78 78 77 75 ...
 $ LENGTH       : num  460 1400 1400 1400 1400 1400 560 560 560 460 ...
 $ DIRECTION    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DateTime     : POSIXct, format: "2020-07-08 12:11:07" "2020-07-08 12:11:12" ...
 $ time_rad     : num  3.19 3.19 3.19 3.19 3.19 ...
```

This is what the graph looks like:

[the graph I have yet, black line represents vehicles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVdOZ.jpg)

It would be useful to have an axis on the right-hand side showing the mean of the amount.

Can you help me out? Would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it be possible to create a reproducible example and tell us how the expected chart should look like?

Comment: Added a graph and some more. Does this help?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot help with this issue. ggplot does not work well with the secondary axis unless it's a linear transformation of the first one. There are some workarounds but it's tedious work...

Comment: Aha ok, thanks anyways!